# Spring MVC + Spring framework 3 + Hibernate 4 + maven 3 in STS of Eclipse 4.3

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

Hi developers and architects.
Our team is going to develop web application in next project,
with Spring MVC + Spring framework3 + Hibernate4 + Maven3 in STS of Eclipse4.3.

I am so ashamed of myself, but I am a beginner of Spring framework3 and we have not much time ... 
Would you tell us NICE sample project or something like "foundation of project" containing these technologies ?

I wish we got happy with Spring in this winter !

best regards.

Comment: spring source github (vote to close question)

Answer (score 0):

I'd completely agree with @NimChimpsky to go with Spring's examples.

However, if you want one I wrote a foundation project that uses Hibernate, Spring and jQuery with Maven.  It collects data from the ESPN API and runs on Tomcat.  Just did it for a simple introduction to Spring and Hibernate for fun one weekend, front end is done with Bootstrap and jQuery, you'll need a MySQL database and a API key from ESPN.

https://github.com/david99world/ESPNPlayerViewer